# Reversi Valid Move Checker

Tags: matlab

I've been doing an assignment which requires me to recreate reversi in matlab.

I have hit a break point where I can't manage to figure out how to do a section of code without turning it into linear indexing.

Essentially what I need to do is figure out a way to add a direction vector (i.e. [-1;0] to go vertically), to my already existing game_state vector in order to find the piece of data above it.

```
    function legal = legalMove()
d_l = [0, -1];
d_r = [0, 1];
d_u = [-1, 0];
d_d = [1, 0];
d_ul = [-1, -1];
d_ur = [-1, 1];
d_dl = [1, -1];
d_dr = [1, 1];
directions = [d_l d_ul d_u d_ur d_r d_dr d_d d_dl];
valid_moves = zeros(8,8);

for ci = 1:8
    for cj = 1:8
        if game_state(ci,cj) == 0   %check element = 0 before continuing
                for count = 1:8
                    d = directions(count);
                    selected = 
                    while selected == player_number * -1 %while the selected piece is of enemy type

                          %move as long as you find your opponents stones
                         if you found at least 1 opponent stone and you end up on your own stone

                         else
                         end
                    end
                end

        else
        end
    end
end
   end
```

My second issue after that, is the actual loop itself.
While I thought that a while loop could be used in order to find out whether to stay on the current direction, I cannot seem to figure out a way to do it myself.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If I understand which bit you're struggling with correctly, you simply need to do something like `sel_i = ci + directions(1, count);`, then similar for `sel_j`, and check that `sel_i` and `sel_j` are within the bounds of the board.

Answer (score 0):

Change `directions` to cell-array that contains strings:

```
...
directions = { 'd_l' 'd_ul' 'd_u' 'd_ur' 'd_r' 'd_dr' 'd_d' 'd_dl' };
...
```

Then next part of the code would go something like this (fill in the blanks!):

```
for count = 1:8
    d = eval( directions{count} );
    ti = ci+d(1);
    tj = cj+d(2);

    % Check if out of the board
    ...

    % Number of enemy pieces you went over
    cnt = 0;
    selected = gamestate(ti, tj)  

    % Move while going over enemy pieces
    while selected == player_number * -1
        ti = ti + d(1);
        tj = tj + d(2);
        selected = gamestate(ti, tj);

        % Check if out of the board
        ...

        % Count pieces you went over
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    end

    % Check if you moved over enemy pieces & whether you landed on your piece
    ...

end
```

Comment: Why would you use `eval` and a cell array for this when the OP already has the directions in a matrix indexed by `count`? Also, your code accesses `gamestate` before checking that `ti` and `tj` are within bounds...

Comment: @wakjah **1)** When OP does `directions = [d_l d_ul d_u d_ur d_r d_dr d_d d_dl];`, he gets 1x16 sized vector. Of course, it's possible to index this vector without `eval`, but not without losing some semantic that OP implicitly warranted for. I wanted to preserve the meaning of his `d_l`, `d_ul` etc. variables. If I would to write cleaner solution I would completely remove those, but would confuse OP, I presume. **2)** I think solution doesn't access `gamestate` before checking `ti` and `tj`. There are checks on two spots in above code. You maybe missed first one?

Comment: Actually, when I try to use this, once finished it returns the error
"Undefined function 'eval' for input
arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in umpire/legalMove (line 204)
    d = eval( directions(count) );

Error in umpire/buttonPress (line 85)
        legal = legalMove();
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback"

Any ideas?

Comment: Zoran, is there a way to contact you outside of the comment section?